# windows terminal move cursor back by x characters

Tags: terminal, windows-terminal

I have made a custom action in windows terminal

```
{
  "command": {
    "action": "sendInput",
    "input": "docker exec -it  /bin/bash"
  },
  "keys": "ctrl+shift+c"
}
```

works great
would it be possible to mvoe the cursor back 10 places so i can start typing the container name after the command is printed out, like:

```
docker exec -it | /bin/bash
```

I know you can do `/r` to execute a return but can not find any info on other things like arrow keys or something like that

Comment: You know that you can switch between whole words in the terminal using Ctrl-Arrow-left or Ctrl-Arrow-right?

Comment: Try this for "input" : `docker exec -it  /bin/bash\u001b[10D`. The code `ESC[#D` is for moving the cursor left # columns.

Comment: @MichaelS. yes I know but it would be cool if the command could move the cursor straight away

Comment: @harrymc that moves it back by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments, Windows Terminal does not implement fully the
ANSI Escape Codes.

You would in this case need to repeat the left-arrow code 10 times,
while according to the standard this could have been done with one
escape sequence.

This value for "input" should have worked:

```
docker exec -it  /bin/bash\u001b[10D
```

The code `ESC[#D` is for moving the cursor left # columns.

This works instead, with the left-arrow sequence repeated 10 times:

```
docker exec -it  /bin/bash\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D\u001b[1D
```

References:

- [Custom actions in Windows Terminal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions)
- [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

Comment: it works indeed tnx